Scale transition doesn't behave as expected
I'm trying to make a scale transition for a VStack enclosed in a LazyVGrid, but it behaves unexpectedly. It slides from the bottom of the screen instead of scaling in place. I know that it should work like that, because I have the same transition for a VStack just a couple of lines above (the "Who is Harry Potter" Text).
import SwiftUI
struct Gameplay: View {
    @State private var animateViewsIn = false
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ZStack {
                Image("hogwarts")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width * 3, height: geo.size.height * 1.05)
                    .overlay(Rectangle().foregroundStyle(.black.opacity(0.8)))
                    .offset(x: 50)
                
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Button("End Game") {
                            // TODO: End game
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent).tint(.red.opacity(0.5))
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Text("Score: 33")
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .padding(.top, 50)
                    .padding(.bottom, 10)
                    
                    VStack {
                        if animateViewsIn {
                            Text("Who is Harry Potter")
                                .font(.custom(Constants.hpFont, size: 50))
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                .padding()
                                .transition(.scale)
                        }
                    }
                    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 2), value: animateViewsIn)
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    
                    HStack {
                        VStack {
                            if animateViewsIn {
                                Image(systemName: "questionmark.app.fill")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .frame(width: 100)
                                    .foregroundStyle(.cyan)
                                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(-15))
                                    .padding()
                                    .padding(.leading, 20)
                                    .transition(.offset(x: -geo.size.width/2))
                            }
                        }
                        .animation(.easeOut(duration: 1.5).delay(2), value: animateViewsIn)
                        
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        VStack {
                            if animateViewsIn {
                                Image(systemName: "book.closed")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .frame(width: 50)
                                    .foregroundStyle(.black)
                                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                    .background(.cyan)
                                    .clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: 20))
                                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(15))
                                    .padding()
                                    .padding(.trailing, 20)
                                    .transition(.offset(x: geo.size.width/2))
                            }
                        }
                        .animation(.easeOut(duration: 1.5).delay(2), value: animateViewsIn)
                        
                    }
                    .padding(.bottom)
                    
                    LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(), GridItem()]) {
                        ForEach(1..<5) { i in
                            VStack {
                                if animateViewsIn {
                                    Text("Answer\(i)")
                                        .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                        .padding(10)
                                        .frame(width: geo.size.width/2.5, height: 80)
                                        .background(.green.opacity(0.5))
                                        .clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: 25))
                                        .transition(.scale)
                                }
                            }
                            .animation(.easeOut(duration: 1).delay(1.5), value: animateViewsIn)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
                .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
            }
            .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .onAppear {
            animateViewsIn = true
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    Gameplay()
}

I tried to change the animation, the position of the animation but nothing really changed, the VStack still slides from the bottom of the screen. I guess it has something to do with the GeometryReader but can't figure out what.

Yes, sorry, that's one of the changes I tried to see, whether it's the fault of the specific .scale transition, or the transition itself. I posted the edited version.

This is due to the laziness of the grid. Can you use a non-lazy Grid instead? It seems like you are always going to have 4 answers. Why do you need laziness?

This is due to the laziness of the LazyVGrid. The animation interpolates between every animatable thing, including the start and end positions of the Texts. Normally these are the same, but a LazyVGrid hasn't laid out the views correctly yet when the animation begins. Therefore, the animation animates the texts' positions from <wherever the LazyVStack initially puts them> to where they should be.
You can use a non-lazy Grid if the laziness is not important to you. There are only 4 texts, so I can't imagine what purpose the laziness serves here.
Grid {
    ForEach(0..<2) { i in
        GridRow {
            ForEach(0..<2) { j in
                if animateViewsIn {
                    Text("Answer\(i * 2 + j + 1)")
                        .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .padding(10)
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width/2.5, height: 80)
                        .background(.green.opacity(0.5))
                        .clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: 25))
                        .transition(.scale)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
.animation(.easeOut(duration: 1).delay(1.5), value: animateViewsIn)

If you do want the laziness, you should not wrap the texts in an if animateViewsIn. They should be in the view hierarchy since the very beginning, so that LazyVGrid can lay them out. You can use scaleEffect to animate the transition instead. This, combined with a geometryGroup, works as expected:
LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(), GridItem()]) {
    ForEach(1..<5) { i in
        VStack {
            Text("Answer\(i)")
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .padding(10)
                .frame(width: geo.size.width/2.5, height: 80)
                .background(.green.opacity(0.5))
                .clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: 25))
                .scaleEffect(animateViewsIn ? 1 : 0)
                .animation(.easeOut(duration: 1).delay(1.5), value: animateViewsIn)
                .geometryGroup()
        }
    }
}


Thank you! The explanation is very helpful!

You can get it working by attaching the animation to the transition and commenting out the animation modifier on the VStack. Nothing else needs to change:
LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(), GridItem()]) {
    ForEach(1..<5) { i in
        VStack {
            if animateViewsIn {
                Text("Answer\(i)")
                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .padding(10)
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width/2.5, height: 80)
                    .background(.green.opacity(0.5))
                    .clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: 25))
                    .transition(.scale
                        .animation(.easeOut(duration: 1).delay(1.5)) //  HERE
                    )
            }
        }
        // .animation(.easeOut(duration: 1).delay(1.5), value: animateViewsIn)
    }
}


